# vim doesn't appear to find .clang_complete

Tags: c, vim, clang, clang-complete

In trying to setup auto completion for C using [clang complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) in vim, and so far, when I'm inside a .c file, I kind of get auto completion when I hit <kbd>ctrl+x,u</kbd>. However it only displays some symbols.

**None of the functions that's in the included headers appear in the auto complete popup box. It appears that only typedefs are showing?**

[image]

The project structure is very simple:

```
$ tree -ap
.
├── [-rwxrw-r--]  .clang_complete
├── [-rwxrw-r--]  makefile
└── [drwxrw-r--]  src
    └── [-rwxrw-r--]  FlightControl.c

1 directory, 3 files
```

I tried creating the .clang_complete file inside the project folder, that contains the following:

```
-I/.../Libraries/xpSDK/CHeaders/XPLM
```

I double checked the path to the XPLM headers, and it is correct.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: try to include also -I../../

Comment: Tried that, does nothing.

Comment: Just deleted .clang_complete to see what happens, and that causes a Pattern not found error, meaning my .clang_complete file is being parsed. But why still, am I only seeing typedefs, no functions at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During completion `libclang` tries to do its best by ignoring errors to present a user with the longest list of matches. I guess that you don't have `XPLM_API` macro defined. As it is used to declare every function in headers, you won't see any functions in completion list. Looking at defines in `XPLMDefs.h` I think that `libclang` gets `Platform not defined!` error (maybe even several times).

It should work if you define your platform for completion, I did this by adding `-DLIN` to `.clang_complete` file and completion works now.

So it doesn't seem to be an issue of vim or `clang_complete`, though it'd be nice to have a warning in such case.